# Creating helper object in the same class magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, helper, dependency-injection

How to **create object in the constructor from the same class?**

```
<?php
   namespace Vendor\CatalogSearch\Helper;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

   class Data extends AbstractHelper
   {
       public function __construct(
        \Vendor\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data $myHelper,  //here circular dependency error
       ....
   }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Please explain what you want to achieve in the first place. Maybe your solution of injecting the class itself is not the right way to go.

Comment: Actually wanted to call function B from A thru $myHelper, anyways using the current object $this, i had used it incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, because of 2 reasons.

1. It doesn't make sense.
2. The factory that should instantiate the object will throw a "circular dependency" exception.

I'll start with the second point.
If you do it like that, when you try to instantiate your helper, the dependency injection container (DIC) will look for an instance of your class to pass it to your class constructor.
But that class instance does not exist, so DIC will try to instantiate it and you are back at the previous step.

And here is why it doesn't make sense.
You would need a dependency on your class because you need to call a method from that dependency, but you can already call methods from your class inside your class. You don't need an other instance to call methods from that.

Comment: Ya i got that Marius, i can use this object to call the function...its working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need such dependency.

If you need to call a function from your helper you can just do the following anywhere in your helper:

```
$this->myFunction();
```

Comment: Yes got, dono why i was calling like that...oops